# Should I save an object with custom data types in Firestore in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uikit

I have a struct called 'AppUser'. In Firestore, I have a collection corresponding to this struct, in which I store all the users of the app. This is how my struct looks like:

[image]

Now, whenever I for instance, want to fetch the friends of a user, I have to make an additional call (so in total 2 to Firestore, one to get my friends and one to get the profiles of my friends) and get the friends by their usernames. If I instead modified the friends variable, to be of an array of 'AppUser', and saved this to Firestore, I would only have to do one fetch request to get all the necessary information of those friends. Would this make sense though? What if users had thousands of friends - the documents would be large and I'd have a lot of data in each document. [image]

Comment: You probably want to save an array of “DocumentReference”

Comment: I see there's an answer but the question is a little vague - when you say *one to get my friends and one to get the profiles of my friends*, what does "get my friends" entail. In other words if the user has 1000 friends, do you want to load every piece of information about every friend? Or just certain things, like their name? Are you storing the friends DocumentID in `friends` or something else? I think the use case needs some clarity. Would storing this users documentId with each friend make more sense? then loading all friends is a snap (query for this users docId on the friends collection)

Comment: „Get my friends“ means the usernames of my friends. I am storing the usernames of these friends in the friends array. I do so because every username is unique, but I’m thinking about switching to storing DocumentReferences,though I’m not sure what benefit that would bring.So if I want to fetch my friends,I first fetch my document and there I’ll find the usernames of my friends. With these usernames I’ll fetch their respective documents. I just need their pictureURLS,fullName and userName. But this means I have to make two fetches,but based on trndjc’s response,this seems to be the best option.

Comment: I won't disagree with the answer but I don't know if denormalizing is the best direction in this use case. If each friend (which would just be another user) simply had a property:`friend_of` and a value of this users `documentId`, then a single query to a `users` collection would return all of this users friends, and any other data required.

Comment: @Jay but that still doesn't scale. And now you've created a scenario where as the app grows, so do individual documents, which is what Firestore wants all of us to avoid. One should design their Firestore architecture for horizontal growth (more documents), not vertical growth (bigger documents), because horizontal growth is the only way to scale to virtual infinity.

Comment: That scales to infinity as a user can have as many friends as they want - and a single query returns them. It's also manageable by paginating the data so the device is not overloaded. I am not sure what you mean by *growing individual documents* as you are not growing whats in a document, other than adding a single property that contains their friends ID and/or their friends id with a value of `true`

Comment: @Jay are you suggesting a single collection of users where each user is represented by one document or a collection of users where a user can be represented by many documents depending on how many friends they have?

Comment: One option is to have a single collection of all users; 1 per document. Within each user you would have a link to the user they are friends with. There are many ways to do that but in it's simplest form, each user would have a property `friends_with: uid_0`. Then when user with uid_0 logs in, query the users node for users where `friends_with` equals `uid_0`, and that will return all of uid_0's friends. One query returns all of the data needed. Obviously this would need to be expanded so a user could have other friends so an array or other container object would be used. Just a thought.

Comment: @Jay but that doesn't scale because eventually the array will overflow the document byte limit. The only option is to use documents as friends. And the only question is whether or not the data should be denormalized.

Comment: Lol. I get what you're asking but focusing too closely on "infinite" can lead to all kinds of thought-provoking issues. For example, the actual 'disk' storage Firebase offers is not infinite so technically it could fill up. If photo type data is stored for an infinite numbers of users, well, boom goes the server. Realistically, an array holds 1,048,487 bytes and that corresponds to about 20,969 friends uids. That's a lot of friends; keeping in mind that while denormalizing is normal, at also means the data takes twice+ the space (cost). Firestore is designed to lesson the need for that.

Comment: I'm convinced by @Jay 's argument. I do not need infinite scalability and denormalization seems to be really bothersome, because you will have to update a lot of documents everytime a user changes something in his document. I think the best way about this is to do what I started with: A collection of users in which every document has uids (or usernames) of friends and friendrequests. This way, I'll have to fetch multiple times instead of a single time but the trade off is worth it

Comment: @Ozgun so you're okay with setting a hard limit to the number of friends a user can have?

Comment: yes - I don't think there is much benefit to be had after, say, a thousand friends/connections on any social media app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise highly against your proposition for exactly the concern you bring up, scalability. Firestore documents can't exceed a megabyte and this approach would not only hard cap your ability to scale but it would be an exceedingly low cap.

What I see, as a starting point anyway, is a collection of users, like you have now. And each document in that collection, which represents a user, has its own subcollection of friends where each document represents a friend. This would scale limitlessly. The caveat, of course, is that it's more expensive.

From here, you have two options. First, each friend document can contain all of the data you need to satisfy the query so that you only need to make a single fetch. This is called denormalization, or the duplication of data throughout a database to prevent the need for multiple fetches. Highly-optimized NoSQL databases, like Firestore, can rely heavily on denormalization, so don't shy away from it if it works for you. The caveat here is that if a friend changes their data, on their own for example, then they must update all of the documents in all of the sub-collections where they are represented. The other option is to simply use the friend document as a bookmark whose purpose is nothing more than to contain the userId of the friend. And so when its time to perform the query, you make a fetch to grab all the userIds and then a subsequent fetch on each friend to get its data.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you see any advantages in storing an array of DocumentReferences instead of an array of usernames? Right now, I am storing an array of unique usernames

Comment: @Ozgun I don't like database architectures that don't scale to "infinity". However, must every scenario in an architecture be able to scale to infinity? Some might argue yes. Others might argue no. The truth is as I see it is that it depends. A Firestore document can contain a single array with thousands of strings representing userIds (or doc references). If you capped the ability of a user to have more than `n` friends, like 5k, then you're golden. Or if this app is for an organization that will never have more than `n` employees, like 500, you're also golden (for now, anyway).

Comment: @Ozgun The question ultimately is, how much scalability do you want or need to have? If you need to be able to scale to infinity, then the prospect of saving friends in a single array in a single document is not even on the table, because it cannot scale. And to answer your question directly about userIds versus document references: it doesn't matter. But if I had to choose one, I'd go with userIds because it makes more sense to me.